Understanding a trade-off in the rate of convergence with empirical means and order statistics.
Suppose $F$ is a continuous cumulative function (cdf) such that $F(0) = 0$ and $F(1) = 1$.
Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables with $F$ as common cdf. Denote by $\mu$ the common expectation of these random variables. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, denote by $\hat{\mu}_n$ the empirical mean $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ of the first $n$ samples $X_1,\dots,X_n$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ denote by $\hat{\mu}^{\text{left}}_n$ the biggest element in $X_1,\dots,X_n$ that is less or equal than $\hat{\mu}_n$.

Question: Is it true that there exists $c>0$ such that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $$\mathbb{E}\Big[\big|F(\mu)-F(\hat{\mu}_n)\big|\cdot\big|\hat{\mu}_n-\hat{\mu}^{\text{left}}_n\big|\Big] \le \frac{c}{n}\quad?$$

My intuition is that what matters is the behavior of $F$ near $\mu$. If $F$ is flat near $\mu$ then $\big|\hat{\mu}_n-\hat{\mu}^{\text{left}}_n\big|$ won't go to zero, but the term $\big|F(\mu)-F(\hat{\mu}^{\text{left}}_n)\big|$ is eventually zero with high probability. On the other hand, say that $F$ is linear near $\mu$, then $\big|F(\mu)-F(\hat{\mu}_n)\big| = \Theta\big(|\mu-\hat{\mu}_n|\big) = \Theta(n^{-1/2})$ with high probability and I think at least the same should hold also for the other term $\big|\hat{\mu}_n-\hat{\mu}^{\text{left}}_n\big|$ (which actually might even go down faster). More in general, it seems that the bigger the term that involves $F$ become (because the cdf is steep near $\mu$) the smaller the other term should be (because there's more mass near $\mu$ and $\hat{\mu}_n$ gets near $\mu$ with high probability).
However, obtaining a relationship that quantifies this trade-off eludes me. Actually, I even got lost in the calculations in the simple example where $F$ is the cdf of some uniform random variable in a certain interval (which might be useful to gain some intuition about the problem).
Do any of you guys have any intuition about how to obtain the desired guarantees? Might there be a counterexample? If there is a counterexample, what if we assume that $F$ is $L$-Lipschitz?
